# Separate numbers from string

Tags: java, dictionary, set, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

/*THIS IS A HOMEWORK QUESTION*/

I have a `.txt` file containing the information:

```
000001    commercial       200000.00 101
000002    commercial       200000.00 101
000003    residential      100000.00 102
```

I need to separate this data into a set, to organize by commercial/residential, and add double value based on the `101`,`102` ID's.

Comment: Please remove all the fluff that I just removed for you: keep your questions short and to the point. And while we're at it: what have you tried so far? Any attempts at all?

Comment: So... there are always a space between them?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I have edited my message as requested and appreciate your help. I have tried to filter the string data using a delimiter "[∧a-zA-Z]+" loop through this information and add this into a TreeSet. I need help on filtering via delimiters(int from String).

Comment: Search online for String.split

Comment: @ Marco, the intended output would be formatted by Commercial Residental hard returns followed by a list of calculated data based on the 101 102 values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to read each line into a string and then use it's **split** method with space character as delimiter.

Comment: So once I am able to separate this data array or likewise, I should be able to input this data into a Set to be called into at Map,right? I need to store each property(Commerical, Residential) into a Set, and calculate the double values shown above from a Map.